# How to properly align lines in report?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services. I have a report with a Page Header and Tablix. The Tablix contains fields bound to the DataSet values.

When the report is rendered, it is not showing lines properly aligned to each other. There are gaps between the lines, as show in the image below:

[image]

While designing the lines are shown as continuous from Page Header to Tablix end, but when rendered, there are gaps and lines are not continuous.

Comment: Eek! Welcome to the wondrous world of SSRS report rendering. This kind of pixel-perfect problem in SSRS can make you start pulling your hair out... Either way it helps if you tell us which renderers have this problem, because behavior can be quite different in the various output formats.

Comment: certain aspects of ssrs are very powerful; some aspects are annoying and badly documented! are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes I am using Internet Explorer and my customers rely on IE only. We cannot change this.

Comment: One option is to use the header within the tablix and set it to repeat on every page

Comment: I had encountered the same issues , and when i played around the DOCTYPE and enclosing the entire report in another container( say rectangle) solved the issue. Sorry, I don't remember the exact solution.. It has been over two years